# How to power 2.5" USB harddisk from ASUS WL500gP v2 router

Tags: usb, router, external-hard-drive, power

I would like to connect my 2.5" Seagate HDD to ASUS WL500gP v2 router and use it for file sharing. The HDD or it's enclosure doesn't have external power cord, it has only one (single) USB cable to connect to PC. When I connect the HDD to PC, everything works great. But when I connect the HDD to the router, the hard drive won't start spinning (clicking sound - not enough power).

Would it be enough to buy an Y cable to use the second USB port on the router to give additional power to the harddisk?

If not, are there any 2.5" HDD enclosures with external power cord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to have a lot of extra hardware so in the end I just bought 2,5" HDD enclosure with external power: http://www.amazon.co.uk/IB-231StU3-G-External-Enclosure-inch-SATA/dp/B004OXY1TU

It didn't come with external power adapter so I had to buy 5V, 1A, 3,5mm/1,35mm power adapter: http://www.ebay.com/itm/EU-5V-1-2A-3-5x1-35mm-Power-Supply-adaptor-Wall-charger-AC-DC-Converter-/170937488309?pt=Multipurpose_AC_to_DC_Adapters&hash=item27ccab13b5

Answer (score 0):

Buy a [powered usb hub](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817182174), plug your hard drive into that, then plug the hub into the router. (Note that not all powered hubs may provide enough power for your drive)

This also has the side effect of providing additional ports if you need them in the future.

Comment: That is another option, but I would like to have it "all in one" if possible. Have you ever seen any 2.5" HDD enclosure with external power cord?

Comment: @JoudicekJouda Yes, there are [many 2.5" USB enclosures with external power](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=Property&Subcategory=92&Description=&Type=&N=100007705+600006260&IsNodeId=1&IsPowerSearch=1&srchInDesc=&MinPrice=&MaxPrice=&PropertyCodeValue=538%3A44401&PropertyCodeValue=538%3A7124).